# Using LeakyRelu as activation function in CNN and best alpha for it

Tags: keras, cnn, activation-function

Since if we do not declare the `activation function`, the default will be set as `linear` for Conv2D layer. Is it true to write:

```py
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
           input_shape=(380,380,1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
```

**I mean now by the written lines, the activation function for Conv2D layer is set as `LeakyRelu` or not?**

Further, I want to know what is the best `alpha`? I couldn't find any resources analyzing it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_%28neural_networks%29?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code,

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(380,380,1))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
```

will definitely transform the outputs from the `Conv2D` using the LeakyReLU activation given parameter alpha ( negative slope of ReLU ).

> Further, I want to know what is the best alpha? I couldn't find any
>   resources analyzing it.

In ReLU, we simply set the activation to 0 for negative values. This causes the dying ReLU problem which leds to overfitting. Hence, we return $x \alpha$ instead of 0, so that the unit does not become non-functional.

If we look at TensorFlow's `tf.nn.leaky_relu` method, we will find that the alpha is 0.2.

Whereas in Keras' `layers.LeakyReLU` class, you will find the alpha is 0.3.

So you can clearly get an idea of what the parameter's value should be. It's basically a hyperparameter which you need to adjust through trial-error observations.